# How to convert MathML to image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mathml

I am creating an arabic app in which user can create Mathematic question with mathematic equation( in RTL format). I have tried with MathML. I want to convert this equation to image and save it. My problem is that i cannot convert it into image.
I am using html2canvas [as in this link.](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

What i am trying to convert is this [image]

what i am getting after html2canvas conversion is this[image]

is there any solution for this?
Or is there any any better way to do the same?

Comment: You can take help from here - http://www.hotelkalika.com/formula.aspx

Comment: @Farook Why you can't use MathML in your app? AFAIK the best option is creating a web app for Firefox and use Mozilla infrastructure to pack it to Android. [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/610) and [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/typesetting-right-to-left-math) does not support RTL.

Comment: @Reniere Silva. I am using MathML. I tried the above example with MathML. Its the only thing i know which support RTL. I tried MathJax and Latex and found they dont support RTL.

Comment: Refer to [How to convert mathml to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32090853/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You can use latex code to generate those type of equations. URL for that - http://latex.codecogs.com.

For your case, it will be http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20%5Csqrt%5B1/2%5D%7B25%7D.

Here, you need to know the input for querystring - your case it is `\sqrt[1/2]{25}` . Here `%5Cinline%20%5Csqrt%5B1/2%5D%7B25%7D` is html encoded querystring.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I have tried latex but it cannot be made RTL. If you notice the equation it is from Right to Left not Left to Right. I tried many ways to do RTL using Latex but failed. Do you have any choices?

Comment: @Farook, that was not specified explicitly for RTL thing, I thought it was mistyped, ok, I will search and let you know.

Comment: Thank you @Arindam Nayak Please inform me as soon as you get one  answer. And sorry that i confused u.